# used wget to download whatsapp and the file name is whatsapp.exe@.... with more suffix after .exe

Tags: download, command, line, wget

I try to use wget to download the file at Windows10, which is the WhatsApp windows version.
the link is https://web.whatsapp.com/desktop/windows/release/x64/WhatsAppSetup.exe

**my command is:**

wget --continue --timestamping --no-check-certificate --content-disposition --trust-server-names --load-cookies --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" https://web.whatsapp.com/desktop/windows/release/x64/WhatsAppSetup.exe

the file name will be as the below:

**WhatsAppSetup.exe@_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=3ded0d&*nc_ohc=-D-89MCjaEkAX8kv64*&_nc_ht=scontent.ftpe8-3.fna&oh=00_AT8UEmzPRwClchv8wl9yIZ-hwOrmqa-crLMO1sQHADPWJA&oe=62AEC4EE**

download log as below:

M:\Software\WhatsApp>wget --continue --timestamping --no-check-certificate --content-disposition --trust-server-names --load-cookies --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" https://web.whatsapp.com/desktop/windows/release/x64/WhatsAppSetup.exe

Cannot open cookies file '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko': No such file or directory

--2022-06-16 12:05:18--  https://web.whatsapp.com/desktop/windows/release/x64/WhatsAppSetup.exe
Resolving web.whatsapp.com (web.whatsapp.com)... 31.13.87.51

Connecting to web.whatsapp.com (web.whatsapp.com)|31.13.87.51|:443... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://scontent.ftpe8-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.16592-6/10000000_2003490039837623_8531027096335135296_n.exe/WhatsAppSetup.exe?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=3ded0d&_nc_ohc=-D-89MCjaEkAX8kv64_&_nc_ht=scontent.ftpe8-3.fna&oh=00_AT8UEmzPRwClchv8wl9yIZ-hwOrmqa-crLMO1sQHADPWJA&oe=62AEC4EE [following]
--2022-06-16 12:05:19--  https://scontent.ftpe8-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.16592-6/10000000_2003490039837623_8531027096335135296_n.exe/WhatsAppSetup.exe?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=3ded0d&_nc_ohc=-D-89MCjaEkAX8kv64_&_nc_ht=scontent.ftpe8-3.fna&oh=00_AT8UEmzPRwClchv8wl9yIZ-hwOrmqa-crLMO1sQHADPWJA&oe=62AEC4EE
Resolving scontent.ftpe8-3.fna.fbcdn.net (scontent.ftpe8-3.fna.fbcdn.net)... 203.74.69.145
Connecting to scontent.ftpe8-3.fna.fbcdn.net (scontent.ftpe8-3.fna.fbcdn.net)|203.74.69.145|:443... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

Length: 151423744 (144M) [application/octet-stream]

The sizes do not match (local 83484672) -- retrieving.

--2022-06-16 12:05:20--  https://scontent.ftpe8-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.16592-6/10000000_2003490039837623_8531027096335135296_n.exe/WhatsAppSetup.exe?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=3ded0d&_nc_ohc=-D-89MCjaEkAX8kv64_&_nc_ht=scontent.ftpe8-3.fna&oh=00_AT8UEmzPRwClchv8wl9yIZ-hwOrmqa-crLMO1sQHADPWJA&oe=62AEC4EE
Reusing existing connection to scontent.ftpe8-3.fna.fbcdn.net:443.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 151423744 (144M), 67939072 (65M) remaining [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: '***WhatsAppSetup.exe@_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=3ded0d&*nc_ohc=-D-89MCjaEkAX8kv64*&_nc_ht=scontent.ftpe8-3.fna&oh=00_AT8UEmzPRwClchv8wl9yIZ-hwOrmqa-crLMO1sQHADPWJA&oe=62AEC4EE***'

=================================

***how to get the correct file name? which option that I need to add to wget command CLI?***

Answer (score 0):

> which option that I need to add to wget command CLI?

You might use `-O name` to specify filename for example

```
wget -O examplepage.html https://www.example.com
```

does save content of https://www.example.com to file named `examplepage.html`

Comment: I knew this option, but some link with the version and the version will change by each release.